# How To Upgrade Meteor 1.2 Version Into Meteor 1.5 Version [ Closed ]

Tags: meteor

Currently my Meteor App running @1.2 version right now I want to upgrade this application into Meteor1.5 version.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While you are in your meteor app's root dir,

To upgrade to a specific version:

```
meteor update --release 1.5
```

To upgrade to the latest version (1.5.1 at the time of writing this):

```
meteor update
```

Comment: Means that can I upgrade directly from Meteor-1.2 to Mteor-1.5.

And there is no need to upgrade into 1.3 then 1.4 and after that 1.5 version.

Comment: @SalimAkhtar that wasn't your question was it. You asked how you can update and blueren told you. If you want to know the smoothed update experience that is a completely different story and highly depends on your app.

Comment: My Meteor application is in blaze